# Achive Google Play Music navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am creating desing for my android app. I have already implemented a navigation drawer but I am having hard time creating UI pattern that I can see in Google Play Music application.

[image]

As you can see they have Navigation Drawer and Tabs in fragment. As far as I have been reading using tabs and navigation drawer is not recommended, but cleary they have something like that in their app. So my question is how can I achive such pattern ?